# SQL Stored Proc eats memory over time

Tags: c#, sql, linq, web-services, memory-leaks

I've been trying to diagnosis this 30 MB memory leak in this webservice.  It has some bulk gets from SQL using standard stored procs.  Each "bulk" returns around 10,000-50,000 rows.  The webservice generates its report and sends it to the caller.

It seems everytime you call for this report 30 MB of memory gets "eaten" and not released. So if you hit the same call about 1,000 times the 3 GB system runs out of memory. If you recycle the app pool the mem is released.  You can sit there for a day and the mem will not be released.  So overtime the webserver runs out of memory.

I steped through the code, anaylysised hte heck out of it, and finally determined it was these 3 "bulk" gets that get a moderate amount of data.  Each takes out 10 MB and doesn't give it back after they're done.  The stored procs are fine.  The only odd thing about the calls is that it uses LINQ to call the stored procs and translate the data into Poco objects, using an XML map file.

I tried changing it so they use a new DataContext every single time the stored proc is called and then set the DataContext to null. I tried setting all sort of objects to null and then calling GC.Collect and the mem is still being eaten and not released until you recycle the app pool.

I would appreciate any leads.  I suspect this has something to do with LINQ and large data returns.

Comment: Would you let us know what language you are using to write the Web Service? This way we can better answer your question

Comment: C# The data is requested using a custom datatype in SQL

 CREATE TYPE dbo.TableOfInts AS TABLE
 ( 
  ID int
 )

Comment: I would look into the translation to Poco objects.

Comment: ie The webservice fills out a DataTable full of the ints of the Identities of the rows it wants, and the stored proc returns the rows.  Obviously this datatable can be huge.  Setting it to null has no effect.

Comment: Is your DataContext wrapped in a using statement?  Are you calling the dispose method before setting the DataContext to null?

Comment: I'm not calling dispose at all.  And not using "using".  I'll try both and get back to you all.  Adrian has some good leads as well.

Comment: That is your problem, setting your datacontext to null without disposing it just removed the reference to it so GC won't remove it from memory.  Remember to mark answer from Adrian below as that was what he was trying to tell you.

Comment: Yeah that makes sense looking at the code.  The DC doesn't seem to know it's abadoned.  The problem is the way they coded it it's going to be rough to figure out a way to convince it that it's been abadoned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the ugly side of having garbage collection: developers tend to think they do not need worry about freeing memory anymore. But that's not entirely true!

Some class instances have to be Disposed (as it's called in .Net). In fact, every object that implements `IDisposable` has to have its memory cycle handled by the developer.

Streams are a good example. Streams are disposable AND they usually carry a larger amount of data (larger than a simple string). Imagine a service where every 5 seconds you handle a 2KB  stream. That's not much right? It's, say, a small XML. But what happens if you do not dispose it? Well, you can do the math yourself, of course, but I'll give you the result: ~33.7 MB of unused junk.

Bottom line: get disposed of your disposables.

Comment: Thats not strictly true. Many objects implement the [Dispose pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1yfkh5e(v=VS.100).aspx) which causes the Dispose to be called when the object is cleaned up by GC. It's a terrible idea to rely on this though, so your answer is still 100% valid. Personally I think of it as a bug, but it's worth being aware of for those times when suddenly an object that used to Dispose by coincidence no longer does due to its reference remaining in scope.

Comment: @MongusPong I tend to always manage my objects life cycle. GC is great, but it has made developers lazy. Many are starting now and don't even know you are *supposed* to manage your objs and that makes me sad. I do not trust GC completely, so I let GC handle the small stuff. **I** manage the big stuff (streams, datasets, etc.)

Comment: Tell me about it. I have spent more developer time tracking down memory leaks in C# then I ever did using C++ due to a lack of developer awareness